# Is the execution of continuous assigmnment statements parallel?

Tags: verilog

In the dataflow description of carry-look ahead adder (a part of the code is attached below), C[1] is dependent on C[0] and so on which exhibits the need for sequential execution. We know that "assign" statements are  executed in parallel, yet this code also gives proper result. How is it possible? Please elaborate on the way these statements are executed.

```
assign C[0] = cin;
assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & C[1]);
assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & C[2]);
assign C[4] = G[3] | (P[3] & C[3]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are executed in parallel, as you say. I think a better word is *concurrently*, which leaves the word *parallel* to describe a topology.

A Verilog simulation is *event driven*. An *event* is a change to the value of a variable or net (or a verilog `event`). When an event occurs, this causes *threads* to execute. Which creates more events, which causes more threads to execute and so on. This keeps happening until there are no more events, when the simulation stops. (This is called *event starvation*.) If the events keep being generated forever, then the simulation never stops (Unless a `$stop` or `$finish` statement is executed.)

So, what's a thread? An `initial` block, an `always` block or an `assign` statement - these are all executed concurrently with each other.

So, how does the simulator know which threads to execute following an event? Each thread has a *sensitivity list*, either explicit or implicit. This is a list of nets, variables or verilog `event`s. Any event on any of these causes the thread to execute. Some always blocks have explicit sensitivity lists, eg `always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)`; others have implicit sensitivity lists, eg `assign` statements. An `assign` statement is sensitive to all the nets or variables on the right hand side of your assignment.

So, the statement

```
assign C[0] = cin;
```

is sensitive to just `cin`. So, it will execute every time there is a change on `cin`. When it executes, it may generate an event on `C[0]`. This statement

```
assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
```

is sensitive to `C[0]` (and `G[0]` and `P[0]`), so if there is an event on `C[0]`, it will execute, perhaps causing a change on `C[1]` and so on.

That's how your code gives the "proper result".

Comment: *"sensitive to all the nets or variables on the right hand side of your assignment."* Plus indices on the LHS e.g. `C[k] = a;` (I made that error many years ago when I wrote an 'automatic sensitivity list' generator/parser. That was before always @( * )  of course :-)